# How to change routes url based on request body in spring cloud

Tags: java, spring, routes, spring-cloud

I want to route requests based on some values in requestBody in spring cloud, for example:

if value of `firstField` in requestBody is chagre, I want to route this request to `/chagre` api
else if value of `firstField` in requestBody is package, I want to route this request to `/package` api

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you need to use an API Gateway. You can do it with Spring Cloud Gateway, and set the rule according to what you need to achieve. Further details here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is not to route according to request body, but use different attributes of the HTTP request instead. Spring Cloud Gateway includes many built-in route predicate factories based on those attributes.

The problem is request body can be read only once. moreover you need to know the object class it contains in order to properly read it.

In order to construct a solution to your question, we can use Spring Cloud Gateway ModifyRequestBody to rewrite the request body after you read it and before it send to the downstream.

[Read more about ModifyRequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#modify-a-request-body-gatewayfilter-factory)

Comment: thank you Yoav, i get request body with implementing WebFilter, but the problem is that urls will set only one TIme in running application, so i can't change it based on request body.